# Сохранение результата в переменной C#

Tags: c#

Народ может и глупо звучить но не как не могу понять почему не работает

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            while (true)
            {
                Console.Write("Введите сумму: ");
                int enterSum = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                int s = enterSum;
                int r = 0;
                MethodCall(s,  ref r);
                BLogic bLogic = new BLogic();
                bLogic.MethodResult(s, r);
            }
        }
        public static int MethodCall(int sum, ref int result)
        {
            if (result != null)
            {
                return result += sum;
            }
            return sum;       
        }
    }
___________________________________________________________

class BLogic
    {
        private int _sum { get; set; }
        private int _result { get; set; }

        public BLogic()
        {

        }

        public void MethodResult(int sum, int result)
        {
            _sum = sum;
            _result = result;
            DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
            Console.WriteLine($"Сумма {_sum} | Результат = {_result} | Дата внесения = {date}");
        }

    }
```

Вот такой код. 
Нужно? что бы при каждой последующей итерации цикла результат становиться (sum += result) то есть введённая сумма (к примеру 500) прибавлялась к результату (который при первой итерации равен  0 то есть результат равен 500). А, при следующей итерации результат который был 500 + введённое число (к примеру 1000) и того результат равен уже 1500. Вроде просто но всё равно не работает. 
 Результат всегда (sum 500 и result 500) при следующей итерации (sum 1000 и result 1000) ну не могу понять почему так. Объясните пожалуйста.

Пробовал и без (ref) результат тот же.

Comment: Вы на каждой итерации цикла заново инициализируете переменные. Вам нужно их вынести за пределы цикла - до while true

Comment: @A K  Спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Никаких передач по ссылке здесь не надо, просто храните данные вне цикла. Также у вас много лишних инициализаций.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   int result = 0;
   BLogic bLogic = new BLogic();
   while (true)
   {
       Console.Write("Введите сумму: ");
       bool ok = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out var value);
       if (ok)
       {
          result += value;
          bLogic.MethodResult(result, value);
       }
       else
       {
          Console.WriteLine("Введено некорректное значение");
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Работает Спасибо!

Comment: А, не могли бы вы объяснить мне эту строчку => `bool ok = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out var value);`Я так понимаю что `bool = ok` присваиваться значение `true` если что то ввели а, в переменную `value` передаётся значение. Я правильно понял? Если нет то не могли бы объяснить.

Comment: @j.Atisto метод переводит строку в целое число, если перевод прошел успешно - возвращает `true`, если не успешно, то `false`, в `value` записывает результат перевода. Строка из которой пытаемся вытащить число - первый аргумент метода.

Comment: Спасибо понятно!